# Unrelated output via iteration of CSV from Python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

thanks for checking out my question.

I am using Python 2.7 on windows 7. My goal is to extract some data (ErrorCodeHEX) from a original CSV file. 
Here is the original data (from a CSV file):

```
AngleInDegrees,DistInMM,Intensity,ErrorCodeHEX
0,2221,259,0
1,2225,244,0
2,2213,172,0
3,2222,98,0
4,2225,87,0
5,2228,82,0
6,2228,84,0
7,2238,82,0
8,2229,64,0
9,2233,44,0
10,2314,17,0
11,2512,8,0
12,0,0,8035
13,0,0,8035
14,0,0,8035
15,0,0,8035
16,0,0,8035
17,0,0,8035
18,0,0,8003
19,0,0,8035
20,0,0,8035
```

I would like to extract the ErrorCodeHEX column and make the look like: `ErrorCodeHEX | 0 | 0 | 0 |...`

However, what I get from my Python code includes the unrelated data (0 to 359):

```
ErrorCodeHEX    
0   0
1   0
2   0
3   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  0
11  0
12  8035
13  8035
14  8035
```

The wired is, I tried the similar code on 'DistInMM' and 'Intensity' columns, they work well. (output just the column in a row)

So I got confused why it does not work on 'Error' column?

Please see code:

def lds_test(self):

```
def my_range(start, end, step):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start += step

# gain distance info
for i in my_range(1, len(result) - 3, 3):
    print result[i]
    log.write(result[i] + ',')  
    result[i] += result[i]

# gain intensity info
for i in my_range(2, len(result) - 3, 3):
    print result[i]
    log.write(result[i] + ',')  
    result[i] += result[i]

# gain error info
for i in my_range(3, len(result) - 3, 3):
    print result[i]
    log.write(result[i] + ',')  
    result[i] += result[i]
```

Comment: What kind of object is `result` and how are you getting it from your file? None of the code you show should produce the unwanted output you describe, but then again, I don't see how it could possibly produce your desired output either (you're writing out comma separated text, not using padded vertical bars). Can you clarify exactly what you expect and what's happening instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with pandas, it will be much faster and easier:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your.csv')
result = "|".join([df.columns[-1]]+map(str, list(df['ErrorCodeHEX'])))
result
```

Output:

```
'ErrorCodeHEX|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|8035|8035|8035|8035|8035|8035|8003|8035|8035'
```

Comment: Hi Tiny, thanks for getting me back. Yes, I agree that Pandas is a useful package for data analysis. But for some reason I got an ImportError 'No module named pandas' after I installed Pandas. So confused now....

Comment: it means you installed pandas incorrectly, can you share your full code please? your above code cannot target your issue.